# Questions on/off topic: computation software file i/o?

Tags: discussion, topicality, specific-question

Is this sort of question off topic?

```
Does Gaussian 09 keep a log of submitted jobs? If so where is the file located?
```

I realize this is not strictly about computation, and may be better suited for stackoverlow because it is about file structures. However, it is directly related to computational software, and it seems users on this SE may be more likely to know the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this sort of question off topic?
>
> `Does Gaussian 09 keep a log of submitted jobs? If so where is the file located?`

It's on topic.

> I realize this is not strictly about computation, and may be better suited for stackoverlow because it is about file structures. However, it is directly related to computational software, and it seems users on this SE may be more likely to know the answer.

The way I see it, you have a few options, in decreasing likelihood of success:

- [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) has some users who do computational chemistry, and that's probably the most likely place to find help. If I were you, I'd probably post there, but it could get bounced here.
- Of course, there's this site, and there have been some computational chemists that peruse the site, but I think any critical mass that we were hoping to accrue has instead accumulated at Chemistry Stack Exchange. So even though your question is good, on-topic, and the type of question I'd want here, I'm not sure anyone would answer it. Nevertheless, you could try, or perhaps recruit people here, which would be awesome.
- [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) also has some users that do computation; sometimes, questions about computation or numerical methods get bounced back here.
- Then there is, of course, StackOverflow, which has been hit or miss, in my experience. You essentially trade-off having a huge readership with the chances that someone might close it for being too niche or off-topic.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot here and see how it goes.

Comment: Well, that didn't last long: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19340/. Maybe it's time to revisit the question of on-topicness of software questions? Current community practice seems to be much more hardline than, e.g., the old consensus: http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/368/

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree that this question falls under "good software question" as in the meta question linked above. Voting to reopen before the discussion happens seems premature, though.

Comment: Agreed. Current community practice seems to shunt everything to mailing lists.  On the one hand, mailing lists are really good for targeted questions about a specific library, if the list is responsive. On the other hand, there's no broader discussion.